# sql join query to check logged-in user liked or not

Tags: mysql

A query really sucks the whole day:(..I am getting a problem while fetching query result.

Scenario: I have two tables where in first table I saved user activity details and second table is used to saves likes functionality of users of all activities entered by other users.

What I need is that to fetch like value whether current logged in user already liked activity or not. I need some sort of boolean value.

**Table to store activities**

[image]

**Table to store like count**

[image]

What I need to check that distinct activity wise logged-in user like check .
   ***Tried Query :***

```
SELECT at.id, 
CASE WHEN lk.status =1 and lk.user_id = 6 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
 END AS l 
FROM activity_transactions at 
LEFT JOIN likes lk ON at.id = lk.activity_transaction_id
```

Output I am getting with duplicates-

[image]

Guys any solution?? **The problem is, I am getting duplicate rows. I need to check 1 if users are liked else 0 for other activity rows.**

Comment: Put distinict because  "like" table contain duplicate value. or else use inner join

Comment: I have tried inner join even distinct but not getting the right output..:(

Comment: try with this query "SELECT at.id, CASE WHEN lk.status =1 and lk.user_id = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS l FROM activity_transactions at LEFT JOIN likes lk ON at.id = lk.activity_transaction_id group by at.id , l". It is working for me for above input tables

Comment: Thanks a lot @KarthickRajan, it's worked.. last group by tweet makes the trick!!

Comment: @KarthickRajan Please turn your comment into an answer so OP can mark as solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this query

```
SELECT at.id,
  CASE WHEN lk.status =1 and lk.user_id = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS l
FROM activity_transactions at
  LEFT JOIN likes lk ON at.id = lk.activity_transaction_id
group by at.id, l
```

It is working for me for above input tables